# Unable to return variable from a function in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a function which will create a directory with time stamp, but when i try to return the directory created i get a blank value
this is the function

```
:createdatetime
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
echo %1
cd C:\somefolder
set hh=%time:~-11,2%
set /a hh=%hh%+100
set hh=%hh:~1%
set mydir=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%hh%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%
set globalvar=try_%1_%mydir% 
mkdir try_%1_%mydir%
set %~2=try_%1_%mydir%
echo %globalvar%
goto:eof
```

This is how i am calling it
     call :createdatetime %%i var2
     echo %var2%
but all i get is a blank value even though  directory is created in the required folder
Please let me know what i am missing.
thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

The `goto:eof` of your function implies an endlocal.

The local variables are discarded then.

To pass a variable back you have to use a set command on the same line/context as an explicit endlocal command.

```
:createdatetime
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
echo %1
cd C:\somefolder
set hh=%time:~-11,2%
set /a hh=%hh%+100
set hh=%hh:~1%
set mydir=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%hh%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%
set globalvar=try_%1_%mydir% 
mkdir try_%1_%mydir%
endlocal & set %~2=try_%1_%mydir%
goto:eof
```

Comment: Worked after changing the %var2% to !var2!. thanks a lot